# Object floating and moving with user movement

Tags: google-project-tango

i'm trying to create a simple Tango application to visualize my 3D models. The problem is that, when I hold my Tango device and move around, I can see my model is also moving with me.

Looks like my physical movement is not reflected in my Tango app in correct scale - like when I stepped for 3 feets, I only moved 2.5 feets or so in the app. However I found other Tango applications on the same device works perfectly - their 3D objects are stable and stays on the same spot without moving.

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: There are so many things can go wrong in your case. Have you tried Tango's example code? They have AR project for C, Java, and Unity SDK. It should be pretty easy to swap out a model using the sample code.

Comment: I am also in same situation